# Camera rotation with a quaternion

Tags: math, 3d, camera

I am having a problem with the maths of camera rotation, well more like I lack knowledge on this subject and can't find anything about it on the internet (read, most likely don't know the correct search keywords)

Anyway, this is what I am attempting to do (pseudo code):

```
    RotateCamera(angle,axis){
        Quaternion rotation = cam.getRotation();
        Quaternion rot = new Quaternion();
        rot.fromAngleNormalAxis(angle, axis);

        rotation.multLocal(rot);

        cam.setRotation(rotation);
    }

    update(float value){ // just to show what input I use the RotateCamera method for the directions
        RotateCamera(value,Vector3f(0,1,0)) // left
        RotateCamera(-value,Vector3f(0,1,0)) // right
        RotateCamera(value,Vector3f(1,0,0)) // up
        RotateCamera(-value,Vector3f(1,0,0)) // down
    }
```

Now this works quite well but sometimes the cam will roll instead of only yaw/pitch. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With just the bit of code given, it's hard to say for sure.  But it looks like you've hard coded the axes of rotation into your update method.  The thing about rotations (whether represented by quaternions or matrices) is that their multiplication isn't "commutative" meaning doing the same two rotations but in opposite orders does not give the same result.

It looks like you're assuming the camera is facing in the (0,0,1) direction, let's call it the z axis, with the y axis (0,1,0) coming out of the top of your head.  As long as this assumption holds, you're axis of rotation for looking up, down, left and right will be (1,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,1,0) as they seem to be in your code snippet.  But say you've just rotated 90 degrees to the left.  This sends the camera's view from the (0,0,1) direction to the (1,0,0) direction.  Now say you make an "up" rotation, which was coded to be around the (1,0,0) axis.  This is a rotation around the same axis in which you're looking, and the effect will be a roll.

Does this address the issue?  If so, you should code your axes of rotation w.r.t. the current direction the camera is facing.

Comment: Basically I should create a getLeft() and getUp() method and use those instead of static values?

Comment: Yes.  getLeft() will just be to determine the axis coming out of the top of the camera's head.  getUp() will then take the result of getLeft() and form its "cross product" (have you seen this?) with the direction the camera facing.  That should do it!